# How to select a date on a website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I don't understand how to choose a date at the website, read all the ways in SO - nothing helped. - https://www.hkex.com.hk/Mutual-Market/Stock-Connect/Statistics/Historic-Daily?sc_lang=en
using selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the human-like interaction (clicking the drop-downs and "search" button) and you only focus on scraping the data, then you could use the url to go directly to the page of a given day.

It looks like:

- `select1` in url is used to choose the day (it's lower by 1 than the actual day chosen because they started numering all possible values from 0)
- `select2` in url is used to choose the month (also lower by 1)
- `select3` in url is used to choose the year (0 is 2018, 1 is 2017)

They don't need to be ordered.